# Abrir ajustes desde app android

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría añadir a una app la opción de configurar la red `wifi` antes de empezar a operar con ella, por lo que necesitaría abrir los ajustes desde la aplicación.

No obstante, tras varias búsquedas en `google` no he encontrado información. Por ello, me gustaría saber cómo abrir los ajustes desde mi app o, en su defecto, como configurar el `wifi` desde la propia app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abrir las opciones de WiFi es bastante sencillo solo tienes que escribir la siguiente línea:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

De esta forma puedes acceder desde tu aplicación a todas los menús de configuración del dispositivo, por ejemplo:

Para acceder a las opciones del modo avión puedes añadir esta línea:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS));
```

O para acceder a los ajustes del Bluetooth

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Por otro lado, si quieres activar o desactivar la WiFi directamente desde el código, aquí esta respondido https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device